# PHP capture errors while saving file

Tags: php, file-io, exception, error-handling

So.... I was writing a small function which returns whether a file has been written or not, as well as the reason why not.... something like:

```
array (
    'success' => false,               // easy, by checking function result
    'reason' => 'Permission denied'   // how am I supposed to find this???
)
```

Maybe I'm missing something, *but I can't seem to find a way to capture any **error messages*** of when saving a file has failed.

The first idea I've had is using output buffering to capture the error, but it is ridiculously out of scope, error prone and a huge hack (ie, a different type of error might interfere).

Usually, this is a good job for OOP-style exception handling, except `file_put_contents` and `f*` functions do not throw any exceptions.

It seems `SplFileObject` does the job...with one exception; it's a line-based class, and [not suitable for reading binary files](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=36289).

Any suggestions?

**PS:** Call me lazy, but I don't believe my code should be checking all exceptional cases (write permission, inaccessible drive, wrong path, etc).

Comment: `file_put_contents` and others will return `false` on failure, so you can check that and then throw your own exception..

Comment: @tandu I need the **reason**, why should I be querying the FS for info on why it failed? Plus, since it's not atomic, it's possible the reason changes between the time of writing the file and the time of checking for errors (granted it's milliseconds, but bad practice is bad).

Comment: If you want to check whether you have the ability to read the file, you can use `is_readable`, `is_writable`, etc.

Comment: Again, that is **not enough**. There are a million reasons why it failed (or `is_writable` returns false), I need those reasons. Get my point?

Comment: What millions of reasons?  You really have a set of arrays that covers every possible reason?  (btw "Permission Denied" is not necessarily a valid reason).

Comment: php offers the ability to do directory / permission checking prior to creating the file.  Possibly the better option is to check directory existence, write ability, permissions...etc and return errors based on that.  Instead of relying on a method to break and handling the exception from there.

Comment: @tandu I already mentioned 3 above - wrong path, wrong credentials (permission issue), disconnected drive.

Comment: @MikeMcMahon That's my point, why do that when PHP does it already? If you turn on error reporting and write a file to drive Z you will get a reasonable warning, rather than a simple 'write failed'.

Comment: then leave error reporting on?

Comment: @MikeMcMahon Wow, how didn't I think of that before! [/sarcasm] Maybe there are ample reasons why one shouldn't be doing that? Or maybe perhaps the PHP script is returning stuff as JSON rather than the mess PHP outputs...?

Comment: Sorry for my tone, but at this point this isn't about getting points for an answer that sounds easy. I have my specific reasons for my question, if you can't play with it, then please don't play at all.

Comment: a plethora of ideas have been handed your way, sorry none of them are matching up with what you are attempting to achieve, but you have to admit.  You've been given good advice, albeit not what you want to hear, it will work and get the job done, allowing you to come back and focus on it later.

Comment: @MikeMcMahon What advise? The thing I was already doing?? See my array code, it already checks the result of `fopen`/`file_get_contents`. Please read the question in full next time!

Comment: Sigh, no of course that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: @Christian: You know that there's a callback when a warning/error/notice occurs? http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: @hakre You know I already mentioned that other unrelated errors might be captured? :)

Comment: @Christian: Define unrelated, you register for your scope and you deregister afterwards. *Update:* Also see here, this might be working: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-notification-callback.php

Comment: @hakre Now that's what I'm talking about.... let's see it doing something useful.. :) By 'unrelated' I meant that if by any chance was relying on custom stream wrappers, and a faulty one kept throwing 'undefined index' notices...

Comment: @Christian: Well that sounds like an error related to the operation.

Answer (score 2):

What you are proposing sounds correct on the surface, have an overarching API which will conduct the basic operation of writing a file to the filesystem. However, I think the PHP devs leave it up to us to put together an API that works for our application needs, as they do provide us the base components to do it ourselves.

Below is a snippet of my `File::write` method I use for my file writing ops:

```
$fileInfo = new SplFileInfo($fileUri);
    
if (!is_dir($fileInfo->getPath())) {
    // I have some proprietary stuff here but you get the idea        
}
    
$file = new SplFileObject($fileUri, $mode);

if (!$file->flock(LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
    throw new Exception(sprintf('Unable to obtain lock on file: (%s)', $fileUri));
} 

elseif (!$file->fwrite($content)) {
    throw new Exception(sprintf('Unable to write content to file: (%s)... to (%s)', substr($content,0,25), $fileUri));
}

elseif (!$file->flock(LOCK_UN)) {
    throw new Exception(sprintf('Unable to remove lock on file: (%s)', $fileUri));
}
    
elseif (!@chmod($fileUri, $filePerms)) {
    throw new Exception(sprintf('Unable to chmod: (%s) to (%s)', $fileUri, $filePerms));
}
```

These are just a few examples of the edge cases you can test for, if you need to test if a "drive is connected", you would call on [is_writable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php). So you could just add it to the list of checks and respond with a message that makes sense for your application.

Then if you want to log said errors just wrap the calling code in a try/catch block:

```
try {
    File::write($fileUri);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage);
}
```

Comment: I was using SplFileObject (with exceptions) and it worked nice, till I realized it only works for text files. I already covered this in my question.

Comment: I read the question, there were several parts upon which I based my answer. Maybe posting the code you are using would alleviate any duplication. As far as testing if a binary image was written, why not do an `is_file` check after your app moves, resizes, uploads the file?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your latter question. I already know if the operation was successful or not, thanks to the result of `file_put_contents()` (or collective result of the `f*` FS functions).

Comment: Your post answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

@hakre just gave me a good idea. It is the default FS implementation that is inconsistent with my system.

A way to solve it is to deregister the default stream wrapper for `file://` protocol and register my own, which actually throws the exceptions. With that in place, I can freely use `file_put_contents()` and catch exceptions at the same time.

Oh, I could also ensure the custom stream wrapper is also atomic (by enforcing locking).

---

Here's what I came up with so far. Of course, it needs real FS check (drive/path existence, permissions, etc).

```
    /**
     * Save file to source DSN.
     * @return boolean True on success, false on failure (see last_error for details). 
     */
    public function save(){
        $file = fopen($this->source, 'wb');
        if(!$file){
            $this->_last_error = 'Could not open file stream';
            return false;
        }
        if(!flock($file, LOCK_EX)){
            $this->_last_error = 'Could not lock file for writing';
            return false;
        }
        if(!ftruncate($file, 0)){
            $this->_last_error = 'Could not clear file';
            return false;
        }
        if(fwrite($file, $this->contents)===null){
            $this->_last_error = 'Could not write to file';
            return false;
        }
        if(!fflush($file)){
            $this->_last_error = 'Could not flush to file';
            return false;
        }
        if(!flock($file, LOCK_UN)){
            $this->_last_error = 'Could not unlock file';
            return false;
        }
        if(!fclose($file)){
            $this->_last_error = 'Could not close file';
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

It *is* quite verbose, and really unlike what I wanted. With the FS checks this will probably increase a good bit.

It's a shame all this code could have been achieved by `file_get_contents()` if it was coded right in the first place.

Comment: Basically what I posted, I don't see an issue with this. You can in(de)crease the verbosity by adding and removing checks. If you opt customize the default FS functionality, post your findings, I'm always down to learn a new way to skin a cat.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm satisfied with either answer, so the game for the better answer is still on (meanwhile, I've upvoted where deserved).

Comment: I favorited the question, interested in the outcome, if a better solution presents itself I may have to update my API. Thanks.